# How to pull max timestamp for distinct sets and subsets

Tags: sql, teradata, common-table-expression, distinct-values, distinct-on

***EDIT: DBMS = Haddoop, Using Teradata SQL Asstistant***

This is the original table. There are 20 location values (c1). Each Location has a set of aisles (c2). I want to get all the set of records from this table for Distinct locations and their set of distinct aisles based on max(tstamp).

| Location | Aisle | Tstamp | qty | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 420 | 4/16/2021 12:22:01 PM | 999 | 999 |
| 23 | 220 | 4/16/2021 11:22:01 PM | 8888 | 222 |
| 31 | 310 | 4/16/2021 10:22:01 PM | 666 | 333 |
| 12 | 420 | 4/16/2021 12:22:01 AM | 666 | 444 |
| 31 | 120 | 4/16/2021 3:22:01 PM | 666 | 555 |
| 22 | 210 | 4/16/2021 01:22:01 PM | 666 | 666 |

I used this
 `SELECT*FROM store_control  WHERE store_control.tstamp  IN (SELECT MAX(tstamp) FROM store_control AS sql2)`

RESULT:

| Location | Aisle | Tstamp | qty | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 220 | 4/16/2021 11:22:01 PM | 8888 | 222 |

What I want is this:

| Location | Aisle | Tstamp | qty | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 420 | 4/16/2021 12:22:01 PM | 999 | 999 |
| 22 | 210 | 4/16/2021 01:22:01 PM | 666 | 666 |
| 23 | 220 | 4/16/2021 11:22:01 PM | 8888 | 222 |
| 31 | 310 | 4/16/2021 10:22:01 PM | 666 | 333 |
| 31 | 120 | 4/16/2021 3:22:01 PM | 666 | 555 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which DBMS you're using, but most databases support [Window Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)).

For example, with SQL Server you can assign a [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) by `Location` and `Aisle` group, sorting by the latest `TStamp` and `Time` first. Then grab the record with row number = 1:

*Note: Since both records for Location = 12 have the same `TStamp`, the query uses `Time` as a tie breaker*

See also [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e316dd21330fe46dd4c8cc099e9e6c14)

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location, Aisle  ORDER BY Location, TStamp DESC, Time DESC) AS RowNum
   FROM   store_control
)
SELECT * 
FROM   cte
WHERE  RowNum = 1
```

**Results:**

| Location | Aisle | TStamp | Qty | Time | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 420 | 2021-04-16 12:22:01.000 | 999 | 999 | 1 |
| 22 | 210 | 2021-04-16 13:22:01.000 | 666 | 666 | 1 |
| 23 | 220 | 2021-04-16 23:22:01.000 | 8888 | 222 | 1 |
| 31 | 120 | 2021-04-16 15:22:01.000 | 666 | 555 | 1 |
| 31 | 310 | 2021-04-16 22:22:01.000 | 666 | 333 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

@SOS's answer can be simplified in Teradata using QUALIFY to filter the results of a Windowed Aggregate:

```
SELECT *
FROM store_control
QUALIFY 
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER(PARTITION BY Location, Aisle 
        ORDER BY TStamp DESC, Time DESC) = 1
```

Comment: Getting ParseException: Syntax Error in Line 3. Could it be my DBMS is Hadoop and my IDE is Teradata SQL Assistant?

Comment: Of course, only Teradata supports QUALIFY :-)